# What is the math behind For loops in this CS50 problem Set with C

Tags: c, math, cs50

I'm currently going through CS50 through edx and doing problem set 1, Mario.

The objective is to create a print out using pound signs. With the help of some videos I got the code for the first one but I don't understand fundamentally how the math works/ what the computer is understanding.

So I figure if I don't learn I'm crippling myself later.

`if n= 5`

Then i has 1 added to it until it is not less than 5 which means 5 times yes?

Take a look at this line for the space loop > 
`for (int j = 0; j < n -1 - i; j++)`

If n is 5, then it ends up being j(0) < 3...

So why on the first line are there four spaces and not three spaces?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Pyramid Height: ");
    }
    while (n < 0 || n >= 24);

    //print out this many rows
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {


        for (int j = 0; j < n -1 - i; j++)
    {
       printf(" ");
    }
    // print out this many columns
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 2; j++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

I get the correct pyramid yet i don't understand the logic behind the spacing and prints

Comment: learn [how to format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and you'll know why

Answer (score 0):

if n=5 then n-1-j would be equal 5-1-0 i.e. 4 for the first time executing the loop that is the reason why you are seeing four spaces. The first loop condition should be n-2-j if you want the number of spaces to be three because total no of columns is 5 and the pounds expected in the first row are 2, therefore you should be subtracting 2 from n.

Answer (score 0):

That looks way too complicated.

Here's a simple version I whipped up:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int height = 5;
    char blocks[height];
    memset(blocks,'#',height);

    for(int i=0; i<height; ++i)
    {
        printf("%*.*s\n", height, i+1, blocks );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 9424KB
    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try to figure out the pattern here. Like for the left pyramid if the height of the pyramid is 8, check the pattern of spaces and hashes from top to bottom. In this case we need 8 lines, every line has same characters and no of spaces decreases and no of hashes increases from top to bottom.

Now we have the pattern for the left half, the right half is the same, mirror image. So now we can write down the loop as we know the no of spaces and hashes from top to bottom. In programming we need to understand the underlying principle. Plug in the code afterwards becomes easy.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int h;
do
{
    h = get_int("Pyramid height: ");
}
while (h<1 || h>8);

int n = 8, i, j;

for (i=0; i<h;++i)
{
    // left half
    for (j=0;j<h-1-i;++j)

        printf(" ");

    for (j=0;j<i+1;++j)

        printf("#");

   // two spaces in middle
    printf("  ");

    // right half, we have omitted the space code as it is not required.   
    for (j=0;j<i+1;++j)

        printf("#");

    printf("\n");  
}

return 0;
```